# Changing the Query Plan

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sybase, database

Is there a way to view the query plan, then change it and set it for a particular query in `Sybase DBMS`. A query can have multiple query plans and the DBMS might be using one of them, which might be inefficient. Can I see it and then change it and set it, so that the `DBMS` starts using the new query plan for the given query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.stf.dmp.doc-SWS-2.0.0/projects/workspace/dmp/en/source/t_obtaining_an_execution_plan.html) explains how to view an execution plan.

There is an entire chapter in the online docs called [Controlling Optimization](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm) that explains how to influence the query plan. I won't repeat it all here, but in Summary you can control:

- [The order of tables in a
  join](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm)
- [The number of tables evaluated at one time during join
  optimization](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm)
- [The index used for a table
  access](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm)
- [The I/O size](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm)
- [The cache strategy](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm)
- [The degree of parallelism](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/X29769.htm)